# sObject type 'MyObj__c' is not supported

Tags: profile, experience

I have an object created that is being queried by code in my Salesforce Experience.  When running as an Admin logged into the Experience, it works fine.  When logged into the experience User, I get the message: sObject type 'MyObj__c' is not supported.

I have also confirmed that the profile of the logged in user's profile has access to the object as well.  Is there a Site setting or something else that could be blocking access for the User?

Using the current hiearchy, I have Account as Private, with an object using 'master-detail' to Account. This object works fine. I have another object which looks up to the previous object with another 'master-detail' which is the 'MyObj__c' and querying data here throws an error.

The query in question is run like this and has no issues running if I change my Apex class to be 'without sharing':

```
System.debug('query = ' + query);//query = SELECT Id FROM MyObj__c
List<SObject> objs = Database.query(query);
```

Also, hardcoding a static query gives the same message as well

```
List<MyObj__c> objs = [SELECT Id FROM MyObj__c];
```

Comment: Can you post the line of code giving this error?

Comment: @fred Pasted my code in as well, there shouldn't be any issue with the code as it runs correctly as other users or with sharing removed.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the error message you get, but by default records are not accessible to external (e.g. Digital Experience) users until you change the sharing settings for an SObject type from the default of "Private" to e.g. "Public Read/Write". (Or use other access granting approaches including `without sharing`.) This is so the data is secure by default: often only some records should be visible.

See e.g. [Set Your External Organization-Wide Sharing Defaults](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_owd_external_setting.htm&type=5) and the screen shot below.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: The issue isn't whether I have access to specific records or not, it seems like the User doesn't have access to the object at all.  Using the current hiearchy, I have Account as Private, with an object using 'master-detail' to Account.  This object works fine.  I have another object which looks up to the previous object with another 'master-detail' and querying data here throws an error.

Comment: I would expect "Public Read/Write" to be required in the "Default External Access" column of the root object with master-detail children inheriting that. Or one of the other access mechanisms to be needed.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why we would need public Read/Write?  Wouldn't that be a huge security issue over having private?

Comment: Yes @dphil. Normally for a portal a user should only see their own records and be blocked from other records. And you are right, that is done by starting out "Private" and then granting access to the records by adding in sharing grants e.g. in the later part of the "Sharing Settings" page though what you can do is limited by the licenses your are using; "plus" ones are need to use "Sharung Settings" otherwise you have to use the more limited [Sharing Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_setting_light_users.htm&type=5). Read/Write is just a way to get the dev started.

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce object was not marked as 'Deployed'.  That prevented the community profile from having access to it.